# Why is Querydsl looking for incorrect generated entities?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, repository-design

I am having an issue where I will get a ClassNotFoundException error when I try to run Junit tests.  The query classes that are generated are QSomeTableEntity_Q but it keeps looking for QSomeTableEntity in the  SomeTableRepository for the entity even though my Predicate class imports the QSomeTableEntity_Q class.

I have in my maven pom 
< querydsl.suffix >_Q< /querydsl.suffix >

Comment: Error Message? Code? "it keeps looking for QEntity" ... Who is looking for QEntity?

Comment: ClassNotFound, can't give code, the spring data repository class for the entity

Comment: one shot in the dark: "Use the goal test-export to add the targetFolder as a test compile source root instead of a compile source root." http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.1.1/reference/html/ch02s03.html or other problems...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like spring jpa framework will look for the q-entity in the domain      class located package.Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Returns the name of the query class for the given domain class.
 * 
 * @param domainClass
 * @return
 */
private String getQueryClassName(Class<?> domainClass) {

    String simpleClassName = ClassUtils.getShortName(domainClass);
    return String.format("%s.Q%s%s", domainClass.getPackage().getName(), getClassBase(simpleClassName),
            domainClass.getSimpleName());
}
```

So just move the q-entity will solve the problem.